# NDSolve error in dde with square root

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have been working on a project involving DDEs and I have an error in trying to solve them with NDSolve, I have tried to eliminate some parameters to find the error and I have realized that it is due to the delayed function when it is inside the Sqrt. Here I post my code:

```
        (*Definition of the constants*)
    \[Theta]y = 10; 
    \[Theta]x = 5; 
    \[Theta] = (100^2*10*\[Theta]x)^(1/4); 
    k4 = 300; 
    k3 = 55; 
    \[Tau] = 100; 
    \[Delta] = 300; 
        (*Definition of the functions*)
H[x_] = \[Theta]*x + 2*(\[Theta]^2/100)*x^2 + 4*(\[Theta]^4/(100^2*10))*x^4; 
h[x_] = D[H[s], s] /. s -> x; 
ys = y /. Flatten[Solve[Y == (k4*\[Theta]y)^(1/2)*y + (k4*\[Theta]y)^(1/2)*y*(A/k3) + 
           2*((k4*\[Theta]y)^(1/2)*y)^2*(A^2/(k3^2*k4)), y]][[2]] /. Y -> H[x] /. A -> 125*k3; 
seqnor[q_] := Sqrt[50*(100/h[x])*((1/100 + (ys*125)^2)/(1 + (ys*125)^2)/
         (1 + 2*x^4 + 2*w^4*4.1)) + \[Delta]*(100/h[x])*(H[x]/(75 + (1 + 2)*H[x])^(1/2))] /. 
     x -> x[t] /. w -> x[t - q]; 
 NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == seqnor[5.5] /. \[Alpha] -> 30, 
      x[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

And I get the following error

```
NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value 1.8803 Im[1/(1. +8.2 x$14770^4)]==0 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.,0.,1.37124}.
```

Does anyone know how I can numerically solve this DDE?.

PS. Sorry for the ugly format of the greek letters

Comment: Have no problem with your code with MMA version 8.0.  Quit your kernel, copy and paste this code and start again.

Comment: I still have the same error, I am working in version 11.3.

Comment: I get the same error in both v10.0 and v12.1, along with some `NDSolve::ecboo`'s.  However `NDSolve` also returns a solution, so maybe they can be ignored?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Mathematica.SE, carlorop! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Mathematica v12 evaluates a smooth result (together with several messages)

Comment: Finally, I have solved the problem just by squaring both terms. Thank for the answers anyway.